# Why can't other users see my hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I am wearing a hat from Winter Bash 2014 (the red shirt) since yesterday.

Other people can't see my hat. If I log out from SE and go to my profile, in fact, I can't see my hat either. Why is that?

Comment: That's not a hat, it's a shirt!

Comment: Off topic: Your profile has "skulls" instead of "skills" you may want to fix it.

Comment: @Ian http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2799572#2799572

Comment: @Ian now it's a hat!

Comment: Now MrUpsidown is wearing an upside-down shirt as a hat. Well done! ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can see your hat, you need to turn this option on (so only users who choose to see hats, can see them). Visitors by default do not see hats. Other users can enable hats by pressing the snowflake in the top menu and clicking on the *I love hats* button.

Comment: That was it! I didn't even think of that. I would say it could be part of the winterbash FAQ. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it answered your question, it happens to all of us!

Comment: @canon If somebody doesn't want to see hats, they at least have the option to not opt-in, so I would say it's a good thing.

Comment: @canon, Funny you should say that, since one of the so-called hats is a mullet.

Comment: That’s a snowflake ❄, not an ice crystal ♢ ;-)

Comment: I forgot the name of it, haha @mirabilos

Comment: @canon If you like your hat you can always go to your favorite image editor and edit it in permanently :)

Comment: How is a snowflake not an ice crystal?